# Where do I find a File menu in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a file menu in chrome from which I can browse my directories and click to open an html file?

This is well written in proper grammar. Why can't you accept it?

Comment: Type `C:` in the address bar to open C drive.

Comment: Did someone tell you it couldn't be accepted? You don't indicate if you've done any research on the topic which is recommended per SuperUser guidlines: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

@Biswapriyo in a comment gave you one way. The other way is Ctrl+O for open will give you as Windows Explorer window to navigate & open files